What is happening to r-MASS 7.3_58.4 package?
Sometime ago, on one windows computer of mine, I have installed r-MASS 7.3_58.4 package using install.packages. I write a lot of code using it. My code runs on this computer.
Today, I try to reproduce my results on another Linux computer. Before doing so, I want to make sure that the environment is the same. This computer uses a conda to install R packages. So I tried to install the same r-MASS 7.3_58.4. However, it tells me that the package is not found. Indeed, when I go to conda forge website, there is no 7.3_58.4 for linux or for windows at all!! The closest ones I can find are 7.3_59 and 7.3_58.3. Meanwhile, I cannot find any news about the removal of this package.
Does anyone know what happens to this package?

Perhaps it updated with no need of keeping the old one. I quite sure most packages have backward compatibility. Consider using the new one and see whether the results do match

Sorry I did not mention it. My code unfortunately does not work on new version like r-MASS 7.3_60 and later. I don't want to debug the code if I can easily get the older version because I know that the code runs on the older version.

I dont use conda and this reads to me like a pure conda question. does conda let you install a package from source ? if so get the source for that version of MASS from the normal places; i.e. https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MASS/MASS_7.3-58.4.tar.gz

Wow, let me try that.

I don't know who maintains the conda verisons, but the version in question seem to have it's source on CRAN https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MASS/MASS_7.3-58.4.tar.gz. That's the official collection of old versions.

Here the link of @MrFlick: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/MASS/

could you add the link to the conda forge web site to your question? That might help people come up with a solution.
